# How do I compile a service worker to a separate location from other JS, using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, service-worker

I'm working on a TypeScript project, so I'd like to be able to write a service worker in TypeScript and then compile it down to ES5.

I've got that working with the following configuration options:

```
// webpack.config.json
entry: {
  app: './src/index.tsx',
  sw: './src/service-worker/sw.ts',
},

output: {
  filename: '[name].js',
  path: __dirname + '/dist',
},
```

This creates a `dist/app.js` and `dist/sw.js` file. However, service workers come with a limitation, which is that they can only cache files that are in or below the directory of the service worker. I want to cache the root (`index.html`), so I can't have it in the `dist` directory.

Is there a best practice for solving this problem? I'm thinking of two possibilities:

1. Compile the service worker to the project root directory. I don't like this option because then my project root will have a compiled file (`sw.js`) with a bunch of directories (e.g. `src` and `dist`) and config files (e.g. `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`).
2. Somehow move `index.html` to another directory and serve it from there. I'm not super opposed to this if it's possible.

Are there other possibilities? If not, which of these two sounds like a better idea, and how would I go about configuring Webpack to solve this issue?

Comment: I hadn't heard of this limitation, can you cite it?

Comment: You could keep the service worker where you want it structurally, and then, in your server, add an explicit endpoint to the worker at a root level.  I would guess that this limitation is imposed client side and if you're serving the worker at `https://my.cool.domain/service-worker.js`, the client won't **actually** know that it's buried deep down in a directory some where.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, one is setting the service worker as static content, pointing to the endpoint you need. 
Using **express**:

```
app.use('/sw.js', Express.static(join(__dirname, '../dist/sw.js'),staticOptions));
```

Other option is to use a [proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). 
Or even you can create an **express middleware** if you need more control over the request.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

  //if req.url is /dis/sw.js
  //rewrite the URL to /sw.js
  req.url = newUrl;

  next();
});
```

These are some options, hope this help to clarify.